# How can I delete a batch file from my PATH created by this python code?

Tags: python, path

Where can I find the file created by this code? I used it to define a function that automatically starts a python file on windows startup.

```
import getpass
USER_NAME = getpass.getuser()


def add_to_startup(file_path=""):
    if file_path == "":
        file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    bat_path = r'C:\Users\%s\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup' % USER_NAME
    with open(bat_path + '\\' + "open.bat", "w+") as bat_file:
        bat_file.write(r'start "" %s' % file_path)
```

Where can I find that bat file?

Comment: btw, I didn't make this by myself. I copied it from another post which is why I don't know how it works fully

Comment: It's in `C:\Users\YOUR_WINDOWS_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. In order to see the folders you need to turn on "show hidden files and folders" in Windows folder settings.